# Git unable to pull/fetch if branch name is invalid on windows

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket

We are using git/bitbucket for scm. It is a big organization and people use different OS for development. People can create a branch or a tag which contains some special characters eg. ", : , >, =  etc. Branches with such names works well on Linux and Mac. However on Windows, these characters are not supported in the file name. If someone has created a branch with an invalid name, my git on windows stops working. I get this error every time, I try to do a git pull or fetch. I cannot even push my changes now.

```
error: cannot lock ref
```

In short my git is broken on windows. I tried to find a solution online, I could not find anything except to delete such files/branches from repository.  That is not a feasible solution for us, as we cannot delete the branches created by others.

Can you please help, if there is a permanent solution for this, that would also work if somebody creates such branches/files in future?

Answer (score 0):

You can at least (as a workaround) create a new branch referencing the same HEAD, and push that new branch with a more standard name.

But another option would be, on the server side, to have a pre-receive hook checking for the branch name, and rejecting the push if the name is not standard.

Comment: That would not solve the problem. I will have to do the same thing for every such branch. As you mentioned, pre receive hook seems to be the only option. Will need to contact the dev ops.

Comment: @sabu I confirm: enforcing a policy is generally done on the server side, with a hook.